# How can I kill a running exe when a particular file is deleted using c# console program

Tags: c#, file, exe, sleep, kill

I have a requirement such that if a file in particular path is deleted, then my program should kill an running exe program and sleep for 5 minutes so that my software will automatically start the same exe again. When the file is present in the directory, it should not do anything but simply sleep for 5 minutes. This program should run continuously and it should check for every 5 minutes if the file is present or deleted and based on the result it should take action.

Here my code is working fine but there is a below issue.

Once if someone deletes the file, the file may come back or may not come back for many days. When I executed my code, once I delete the file from the folder it keeps on killing the exe file in every 5 minutes cycle. But it should not do that way instead it should work like, as already file has deleted in this cycle and it killed exe, in the next cycle it should not kill exe even if there is no file. it should kill only if file comes back again and gets deleted.

Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string path = "C:\\Experiment\\folder\\database\\data.tou";
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                    if (pname.Length > 0)
                    {
                        pname[0].Kill();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a malware killing antivirus?

Answer (score 0):

> in the next cycle it should not kill exe even if there is no file. it should kill only if file comes back again and gets deleted.

Picture this as an `if` condition.  What would that condition need to check?

- Does the file exist or not?
- Did the file exist the last time I checked?

You're currently checking the first condition, but not the second.  And in order to check that second condition, the application will need to *remember something from the past*.  The way to do that is to persist that information somewhere.  You could persist it in a database, in a file, or any other storage medium of your choice.

Heck, since the application itself is just an infinite loop, you may even be able to just persist it in a variable.  For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filePreviouslyExisted = false;

    while (true)
    {
        string path = "C:\\Experiment\\folder\\database\\data.tou";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            filePreviouslyExisted = true;
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
        else
        {
            if (filePreviouslyExisted)
            {
                filePreviouslyExisted = false;
                Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                if (pname.Length > 0)
                {
                    pname[0].Kill();
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
}
```